# How to calculate zoom URL parameter at the Google Maps Preview (new version GM)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to write chrome extension which references on new version of Google Maps site.

BUT, in new google maps preview i can not give link becouse i can't calculate new zoom parameter.

For example, URL new google maps:
https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d4112402!2d-62.7728736!3d44.829016

new zoom parameter are very strange:

```
zoom 23 http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 1145       !2d29.6765085!3d59.868445
...
zoom 12 http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 77910      !2d29.6765085!3d59.868445
zoom 11 http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 155852     !2d29.6765085!3d59.868445
zoom 10 http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 311710     !2d29.6765085!3d59.868445
zoom 9  http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 623333     !2d29.568544!3d59.8698115
zoom 8  http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 1247028    !2d29.568544!3d59.8698115
zoom 7  http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 2493322    !2d29.568544!3d59.8698115
zoom 6  http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 4987951    !2d29.568544!3d59.8698115
zoom 5  http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 9979726    !2d29.568544!3d59.8698115
zoom 4  http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 19959453   !2d29.568544!3d59.8698115
zoom 3  http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 40027823   !2d29.568544!3d52.0636483
zoom 2  http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 80266577   !2d29.568544!3d48.7705008
zoom 1  http://google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d 100000000  !2d29.568544!3d47.3841015
     ↑                                                       ↑           ↑            ↑     
old google                                      new zoom parameter      LAT         LONG
maps zoom                                       on Google Maps Preview
parameter                                       depends on coordinates
intuitive and easy                              how to calculate it?
```

**This parameter depends on coordinates!**

How can i generate link on new google maps with this zoom, if i know old zoom parameter (from 1 to 23)?

I think I need a new weird setting for a new function Globe... but i don't know how to compute this... google search don't know answer

If zoom parameter is bad - maps redirect to home location.

[image]

Comment: There's some more info which seems to work on a similar question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939725/why-has-google-maps-q-parameter-stopped-working

Answer (score 6):

How about using the alternative `@` syntax when linking to the maps?

#### Template:

`https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/@{LATITUDE},{LONGITUDE},{ZOOM}z`

#### Example:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/@29.6765085,59.868445,12z
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/@29.6765085,59.868445,11z

Comment: In the current version of Google Maps, the `{ZOOM}z` parameter is becoming a `{OBS}m` parameter, which seems to be the distance of the observer/view point from the surface.  

Try using a parameter bigger than `10000000m` :-) )

Comment: what about sattellite view? There is no zoom parameter. Only "meters" instead zoom
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@29.6765085,59.868445,25772m/data=!3m1!1e3