# Why has google maps "q" parameter stopped working?

Tags: google-maps

We have an app which launches google maps to display a location using the following form of link ([as per the recommendations on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon)):

```
http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=loc:52.03877,-2.3416&z=15
```

For some reason though, instead of pointing me at that lat/lon, google maps now [points](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=loc:52.03877,-2.3416&z=15) me at Worcester instead of Hollybush near Malvern.

Has the google maps API changed? ..and if so, what is the correct way to do what we used to do?

Comment: Did you try reading the actual docs? https://developers.google.com/maps/web/

Comment: Yes but those all seem to pertain to using the javascript api or embedding a map. I just want to launch google maps via a URL. Is that covered somewhere else or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: This has nothing to do with any maps-API. None of these features have ever been documented officially, so there isn't any correct way.

Comment: How about ```google search``` ```q``` query doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit of experimentation suggests the following works (note the addition of the '@' symbol):

```
http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/place/52.03877,-2.3416/@52.03877,-2.3416,15z/data=!3m1!1e3
```

I found [some more information here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582066/how-to-calculate-zoom-url-parameter-at-the-google-maps-preview-new-version-gm).

Comment: Seems to work without the @ symbol too, but since the eventual redirected-to URL has an @ that seems like the safest course.

Comment: One thing I _can't_ seem to work out is how to get google maps to show a satellite view from the URL..

Comment: my guesswork resulted in the following, where 18z is for zoom and 1e3 for satelite (4b1 would be map). wonder what the other parameters in data are for?

 https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/52.03877,-2.3416/@52.03877,-2.3416,18z/data=!3m1!1e3!

Comment: @xordon; that doesn't work with the new iteration of google maps hence my post here..

Comment: I was referring to the "t" parameter. That controls the map type.

Comment: The 't' parameter doesn't seem to work in the new maps either: http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=@52.03877,-2.3416&z=15&t=e

Comment: Also the &z=15 doesn't do a thing. That is why I posted a variation above where maptype and zoom is working.

Comment: Agreed munomono; your suggestion is working well - Thanks! :)